# T-SQL - Non optimal plan is used - WHERE clause should be shortcircuited

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

We have many "search stored procedures" that take multiple nullable parameters for searching rows of data in different tables. They're usually built like this:

```
SELECT      *
 FROM       Table1 T1
 INNER JOIN Table2 T2
     ON     T2.something = T1.something
 WHERE      (@parameter1 IS NULL OR T1.Column1 = @parameter1)
        AND (@parameter2 IS NULL OR T2.Column2 = @parameter2)
        AND (@parameter3 IS NULL OR T1.Column3 LIKE '%' + @parameter3 + '%')
        AND (@parameter4 IS NULL OR T2.Column4 LIKE '%' + @parameter4 + '%')       
        AND (@parameter5 IS NULL OR T1.Column5 = @parameter5)
```

This can go on for up to 30-40 parameters and what we've noticed is even if only parameter1 is provided, the execution plan goes through index scans of the other tables which can slow down the query significantly (few seconds). Tests show us that keeping only the first line from the WHERE statement makes the query instant.

1. I've read that shortcuiting is not possible, but are there work around or ways to construct queries that would possibly be more efficient?
2. We currently work around this problem by having different versions of the same SELECT/FROM/JOINS but with different set of parameters in the WHERE clause and depending on which parameters are passed we choose the proper select statement to go through. This is long, messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: Have you considered using [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)? Even with the [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) caveat it may be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Build parameterized dynamic sql and sql injection isn't a problem

Comment: I'll take a look again at dynamic sql, but it seems just going back to how we used to do things and build complex strings of SQL code within the applications themselves with bunch of conditions that made it nearly impossible to understand the query at a quick glance. Also is there a way to keep syntax highlighting/tools within SQL management studio for those queries?

Answer (score 4):

The query plans in SQL Server is compiled and stored for reuse. Even if SQL Server sees that your parameters are `null` it has to come up with a query plan that will work for the cases where they are `not null`.

Query hint `option (recompile)` was introduced in SQL Server 2005 but it was not until SQL Server 2008 that it actually had an effect on the kind of query you have here.

When the query is recompiled every time it will not be stored in the query plan cache so SQL Server is free to optimize out the checks against parameters that is `null`.

Read more about it here [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Some sample code you can test on to see the difference in query plans. The first call to the SP will do a index seek and the second will do a clustered index scan.

```
create table T
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int
);

go

create index IX_T on T(Col1);

go

create procedure GetT
  @Col1 int,
  @Col2 int
as

select ID
from T
where (Col1 = @Col1 or @Col1 is null) and
      (Col2 = @Col2 or @Col2 is null)
option (recompile);

go

exec GetT 1, null
exec GetT 1, 1
```

Comment: I've used this approach to great success.  The only issues I've had are when the number of compiles becomes an issue.  After that, dynamic parameterized sql is the only real option.

Comment: What do you mean by the number of compiles becomes an issue?

Comment: @FrancoisCN Compiling the query takes resources (CPU) on the server and using `option (recompile)` means that the query will be compiled for each execution. So using it might put a strain on your server. How big the impact is depends on the complexity of the query and how often it is executed.

Comment: +1 The _Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL_ article you linked to is simply brilliant.